# Get the count of result lines

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I try to do something in JS and PHP.

I call a PHP file in Ajax and I want this code to return the count of result lines. So I echo it :

```
$connexion = new PDO($source, $utilisateur);
$requete = "SELECT * FROM scores WHERE pseudo = '".$_POST['login']."' AND Score >= 0";
$resultat = $connexion->query($requete);

echo ($resultat->rowCount());
```

And when I attempt to get it in the done in Ajax it doesn't works, it return a fatal error : "Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object".

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../php/levelState.php",
    type: "POST"
}).done(function(levelUnlocked) {
    // Affichage de l'écran de sélection 
    $("#title, #game").hide();
    $("link").attr({rel:"stylesheet", href:"../css/select.css"});
    $("#select").fadeIn("slow"); 
    for (var i = 0; i < levelUnlocked; i++) {
        $('#' + parseInt(levelUnlocked + 1)).removeClass('levelLock').addClass('level');
    } 
});
```

});

Thanks for help !

Comment: Your php script is borked, fix that. You should also, in my opinion, return json in in PHP script so that it sends something JS can easily work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request return null. When you do `$resultat->rowCount()` your app produce a Fatal error. You should check if your `$resultat` is empty or not.

Anyway, your current query is equal to: `"SELECT * FROM scores WHERE pseudo = '' AND Score >= 0";`. That's why you got this error. By the way **you should use prepared statement**.

To solve your problem, you should specify which data you sent in your ajax function (I've added the keyword `data`).

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../php/levelState.php",
    data: { login: $("#selector-login").val() } // You should add something like this
    type: "POST"
}).done(function(levelUnlocked) {
    // Affichage de l'écran de sélection 
    $("#title, #game").hide();
    $("link").attr({rel:"stylesheet", href:"../css/select.css"});
    $("#select").fadeIn("slow"); 
    for (var i = 0; i < levelUnlocked; i++) {
        $('#' + parseInt(levelUnlocked + 1)).removeClass('levelLock').addClass('level');
    } 
});
```

Comment: You were right, the $resultat var was false, I have any error yet. I did like your example, so I passed data, but in fact if I understand my request can find results ? I have one value corresponding to the query...

Comment: Problem solved ! There was no results because I did a mistake in the name of the table forms...

Comment: I'm glad it helped. You can consider the answer of @gnarly about prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

> PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure.

My best guess is that your query is failing and the value of $resultat is FALSE, that's why you cannot run rowCount() method on it.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your PHP, I'd do something like this.

```
header('Content-Type:application/json');
$connexion = new PDO($source, $utilisateur);
$stmt = $connexion->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM scores WHERE pseudo = ? AND Score >= 0");
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['login']));
$res = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
echo json_encode(array_pop($res));
```

Comment: I forgot to give the login value, but yet I fixed it. 

I'm trying to understand your response, but in this case, the query can't fail because there is at least on score registered.

Comment: Try running your PHP script without using Ajax and debug your database call. There's something that's tripping up your db call, could be a problem with your database connection or table structure. Without an actual error message, I can't help.